# OpenGL - Share existing textures with future contexts?

Tags: c++, c, windows, opengl

I have an application where I draw frames to a texture using the FBO extensions.

These frames are then be displayed to different windows that are opened **while** the application is running. This means that textures can be created and pooled before the OpenGL context for any new window is created and `wglShareLists` is called.

Currently I have to do `glReadPixels`, `glMapBufferRange` and `glTexSubImage` to move the texture into the different window contexts, which is rather inefficient.

Any ideas on how to improve on this? Should I create multiple (as much as the maximum number of windows at any time ~4) OpenGL contexts and hidden windows during program startup? What would be the overhead of that?

Or even better, is there a way to make textures shared between existing and **future** OpenGL contexts?

Comment: not sure for windows, but on linux you can create windows with shared OpenGL context. maybe something similar can be done for windows

Comment: @BЈовић: But when you create a new context which shares resources with a "main" context. Are resources that are **already** created (before the new context) in the "main" context shared as well?

Comment: @ronag: Yes, they are shared. In fact it is mandatory to create the sharing, before creating any new textures or other names objects in the new context, as creating names before the sharing may result in namespace collisions. However if you just want to render to multiple windows: It is perfectly possible to use a single OpenGL context on an arbitrary number of windows, as long as their PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR is compatible. That's what the HDC parameter of wglMakeCurrent is meant for. If a context was strictly bound to a single window, wglMakeCurrent had only a HRC parameter.

Comment: @datenwolf: It seems to me that you are contradicting yourself. What I think you meant to say is that they are not shared? Or do you mean that objects created in the "main" context before sharing are ok, but not for objects that are created in the "new" context before sharing?

Comment: @datenwolf: Good point! Maybe I can skip the extra context.

Comment: @ronag: Already created objects are shared. But this of course requires precautions, because what would happen if both context A and B had textures with ID=1? If however A had a lot of textures and B none, then the texture names of A can be transferred to B just fine. That's the caveat. Or, yes, like you formultated it ,,objects created in the "main" context before sharing are ok, but not for objects that are created in the "new" context before sharing``.

Comment: @datenwolf: If you put all this useful info into an answer, then I could accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sharing Lists between OpenGL contexts will share all data encapsulating buffer objects as well (textures, vertex buffer objects, pixel buffer objects) but not abstract collection objects (framebuffer objects, vertex array objects). It is mandatory to create the sharing, before creating any new named objects in the new context, as creating names before the sharing may result in namespace collisions. Already created objects are shared. But this of course requires precautions, because what would happen if both context A and B had textures with ID=1? If however A had a lot of textures and B none, then the texture names of A can be transferred to B just fine. That's the caveat.

However if you just want to render to multiple windows: It is perfectly possible to use a single OpenGL context on an arbitrary number of windows, as long as their PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR is compatible. That's what the HDC parameter of wglMakeCurrent is meant for. If a context was strictly bound to a single window, wglMakeCurrent had only a HRC parameter.

Comment: Thanks again for that very detailed information. I was facing a similar problem and overread the part of "The handle can be used (via wglMakeCurrent or wglMakeContextCurrentARB) with any HDC sharing the same pixel format as <hDC>, and created on the same device, subject to constraints imposed by the API version." from the official documentation.
Your answer brought me on the right way :)