# Draw framebuffer to different windows

Tags: opengl, glfw

I wonder how to draw a framebuffer to two different windows.
I use glfw to create the windows and I create the second window like this:

```
GLFWwindow* second_window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Second Window", NULL, first_window);
```

I create the framebuffer in the context of window 1, but how do i draw that framebuffer to the second window?
I can navigate and click on stuff from window 2 but no image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Sharing a context (as you do at second_window creation) allows sharing also a [Renderbuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object). A RBO is used in a [FBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) which is not the same as the default frame buffer

Comment: So can i make the second window share the same framebuffers or what do you mean?
Ideal for me would be if it's possible to:
foreach window in windows draw finalRenderFBO to screen quad in window.
Is that possible?

Comment: Default frame buffer and FrameBuffer objects aren't shareable. But you can render to a RBO and blit it in the second window.

Comment: datenwolf's answer here may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581303/opengl-share-existing-textures-with-future-contexts

Comment: Datenwolfs answer sounds like what i need to do.  Are compiled shader programs shared aswell? Or would i have to create a toscreen shader program in context 2 aswell? If my Glint RBO has the value 10 in context 1, should i bind 10 in the second context?

Comment: Thanks guys, solved it.
I draw my scene to a texture and then created a shader program for each context. The shader program draw the texture on to a screen quad to the backbuffer of that window.